# What is a example of a target platform in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl, target, platform

What is an example of a target platofrm in OpenCL? is it, for example, an OS like Windows, Android, Mac, or is it the actual chips in a device?

Answer (score 6):

An OpenCL platform is essentially an OpenCL implementation. It is not related to the operating system (if any). It is commonly related to the hardware chip, but not necessarily. For example, the AMD platform also supports Intel CPUs. Another example is the Beignet project, an open-source OpenCL platform which runs on Intel hardware, or Pocl, which runs on ARM and x86.

Some examples of existing OpenCL SDKs/platforms (I don't have their full names at hand so I'll just list the vendor/SDK name):

Proprietary:

- [Intel® SDK for OpenCL™ Applications](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-opencl)
- [AMD APP SDK](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/)
- [NVIDIA OpenCL](https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl)
- [ARM Mali OpenCL SDK](http://malideveloper.arm.com/develop-for-mali/sdks/mali-opencl-sdk/)
- [Apple OpenCL](https://developer.apple.com/opencl/)
- [Qualcomm Adreno SDK](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/maximize-hardware/mobile-gaming-graphics-adreno/tools-and-resources)
- [Imagination Technologies OpenCL on PowerVR](http://community.imgtec.com/developers/powervr/powervr-gpu-compute/)

There are also implementations by IBM, Samsung, Altera, Vivante, Xilinx, MediaTek, STMicroelectronics...

Open Source:

- [Beignet](https://01.org/beignet)
- [Portable Computing Language](http://portablecl.org/)

This list is not exhaustive.

Comment: What about [Clover](http://people.freedesktop.org/~steckdenis/clover/index.html)?

Comment: I don't know enough about it.